# OnHandleIntent not being called in an Intent Service

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I have an intent service that I'm starting on a separate process (I have it included in the manifest), and the process is being started, but the logs I have at the beginning of OnHandleIntent are never called. I'd like this to be in a separate process because it's doing some heavy lifting and needs all the memory it can get its hands on.

This is the service code:

```
public class ProcessingService extends IntentService {

private final String TAG = "Processing Service";

public ProcessingService() {
    super("ProcessingService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "On Handle started");

/../

}
}
```

And here is where I'm starting it:

```
public void doneBtn(View v) {

    Log.d(TAG, "button pressed, starting service");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ProcessingService.class);
    startService(intent);
    finish();

}
```

I've also tried calling the service with the application context, same results.

And of course in the manifest, inside the application scope:

```
<service android:name=".myapp.task.ProcessingService" android:process=":myserviceprocess"/>
```

The button is pressed, the process is created and the activity finishes, but the log in onHandleIntent is never fired (and none of the other work in there is done). Is there something wonky about putting an Intent Service on a separate process? Should I do a regular service then spawn an async task off of it or something?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the android:process attribute from the Manifest?

Comment: no, same results (except obviously no new process gets created)

Answer (score 0):

The same code is working fine for me. I would like you to try a couple of things to debug this issue: -

- Try debugging it. Put a breakpoint in your Service class' onHandleIntent() and see if control ever reaches there.
- Try removing finish() after calling startService() and see if it works.

Comment: Tried the break point, never reaches it. Tries removing finish, same deal. Some new behavior though, some of the time when I test it the service gets an ANR, again before ever reaching onHandleIntent, and I tried putting it back on the same process as the application, with the same result. I don't have any code other than a constructor with a call to the super and what I have in onHandleIntent.

Comment: can you post or share the code of your Activity calling the service? Is there anything else going on in your app that could be causing the ANR?